# void struct linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

how can I link a linked list when this is a void struct, I will give an example,

```
struct tmpList *addToken2TmpList(struct tmpList *headTmpList, char *token)
{
    struct tmpList *tokenNode = (struct tmpList *)malloc(sizeof(struct tmpList));
    tokenNode->data = token;
    tokenNode->next = NULL;

    return cocatenateNodes((struct tmpList *)tokenNode, (struct tmpList *)headTmpList);
}

void *cocatenateNodes(void *node, void *headNode)
{
    void *tmp = headNode;

    if (headNode == NULL)
    {
        headNode = node;
    }
    else
    {
        while (tmp->next != NULL)
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next = node;
    }

    return headNode;
}
```

the compilation fails that it does not recognize tmp->next, how can I fix it?

Comment: Why do you want to deal with `void*` instead of `struct tmpList*`?

Comment: You have to tell the compiler the actual structure while referencing the void pointer, with the help of cast. A void is just a pointer.

Comment: could you please post the defintion of `tmplist`? And why do you want to handle it as `void*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot work as `void` does not contain any member `next`.

You must use your node structure `struct tmpList *` to access any members.
Functions dealing with list manipulation should use the prope node type in the signature to get some type safety.
If you really want to use `void *` in the signature, you must cast the pointer to `(struct tmpList *)` inside your function.
Otherwise you will not be able to access members.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast tmp as a tmpList*. And write something like that:

```
((struct tmpList*)tmp)->next = node;
```

But if you want to use a void type, it means your `headNode` variable should be of any type and you need to give a parameter to the function to know the type of structure you want to access and cast it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change `cocatenateNodes` to work with `struct tmpList *` instead of `void *`. And you can remove several unnecessary casts in `addToken2TmpList`.

```
struct tmpNode *cocatenateNodes(struct tmpNode *node, struct tmpNode *headNode);

struct tmpList *addToken2TmpList(struct tmpList *headTmpList, char *token)
{
    struct tmpList *tokenNode = malloc(sizeof(struct tmpList));
    tokenNode->data = token;
    tokenNode->next = NULL;

    return cocatenateNodes(tokenNode, headTmpList);
}

struct tmpNode *cocatenateNodes(struct tmpNode *node, struct tmpNode *headNode)
{
    struct tmpNode *tmp = headNode;

    if (headNode == NULL)
    {
        headNode = node;
    }
    else
    {
        while (tmp->next != NULL)
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next = node;
    }

    return headNode;
}
```